# RSelenium on docker: where are files downloaded?

Tags: r, selenium, docker, containers, rselenium

I am using Selenium using a docker image:

```
require(RSelenium)

  if (length(system("docker ps -l", intern = TRUE))<2)
    try({system("docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0")})
```

It works, I can connect to any url and navigate. However when I click a button to download a file, it sometimes saves it (partially, saved as `xxxxxxx.csv.part`) to `/tmp/mozilla_mozillaUser0`, and sometimes to ... nowhere, or maybe another location I cannot find...

Is there a reason for that?

Also I tried to open the driver using

```
makeFirefoxProfile(list(browser.download.dir = "D:/temp"))
```

but it returns a weird error

```
Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"zip" -r9Xjq "C:\Users\rocks\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPhjUb\file31076202d4f.zip" "C:\Users\rocks\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPhjUb/firefoxprofile/prefs.js" ' had status 127 
2: In file(tmpfile, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\rocks\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoPhjUb\file31076202d4f.zip': No such file or directory
```

where I can understand why this desn't work given that all links are in windows but my selenium runs in a docker container or Ubuntu.

My Setup: R running on Windows, and I have a docker image of Ubuntu that contains the selenium server.

**EDIT:** *turns out my issue was because firefox was not installed on the host machine* (which is not needed in theory).
I fixed the issue by using (instead of invoking `makeFirefoxProfile`):

```
fprof = structure(list(firefox_profile = "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"), .Names = "firefox_profile")
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = ePrefs, port = 4445)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The docker container is a separate entity to the HOST which is running it. You need to map a directory on the HOST to a directory on the container you download files to:

You can do this when starting your container:

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 -p 5901:5900 -v /home/john/test:/home/seluser/Downloads selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1
```

Here (i am running docker on linux) I have mapped a directory on my linux HOST (/home/john/test) to a directory on the container (/home/seluser/Downloads).

We then need to add the necessary information to the firefox profile:

```
library(RSelenium)
ePrefs <- makeFirefoxProfile(
  list(
    browser.download.dir = "/home/seluser/Downloads",
    "browser.download.folderList" = 2L,
    "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting" = FALSE,
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" = "multipart/x-zip,application/zip,application/x-zip-compressed,application/x-compressed,application/msword,application/csv,text/csv,image/png ,image/jpeg, application/pdf, text/html,text/plain,  application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/x-excel, application/x-msexcel, application/octet-stream"))
remDr <- remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = ePrefs, port = 4445)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/")
firstzip <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//a[contains(@href, 'zip')]")
firstzip$clickElement()
```

We can check if the download is on the HOST machine:

```
> list.files("/home/john/test/")
[1] "peace.zip"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to map the drive. However when running your `makeFirefoxProfile` command, I get this error message:
`Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"zip" -r9Xjq "C:\Users\rocks\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuI1GbG\file21f47211278c.zip" "C:\Users\rocks\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuI1GbG/firefoxprofile/prefs.js" ' had status 127 
2: In file(tmpfile, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\rocks\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuI1GbG\file21f47211278c.zip': No such file or directory`

Comment: It seems it is because firefox is not installed on my host machine. Doesnt seem to be needed in theory! It is a bit weird to create a firefox profile on the host to apply it on the guest...

Comment: If your HOST is a windows machine you will need commandline zip. Check out `?makeFirefoxprofile` for details. The easiest way to get this is to install  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Old thread I know, but I wonder if @jdharrison or anyone else can say why I would be getting the "Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection..." problem when running makeFirefoxProfile on an Amazon Linux machine??

Comment: @jdharrison Thanks for posting this. I think this is working for me, as everything runs smoothly but when I click on a download button with a file behind it, it doesn't show up in the directory I specify. I think the issue is I don't know where the directory on the docker container is that I'm supposed to map? I'm on linux as well and pretty inexperienced with docker. Do you know where it might be? I am also on linux and have a selenium folder in my home directory with the 3.141.59 .jar file in it and the v.025.0 geckodriver .tar.gz file in my home directory